# Re-route [router]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

*NOTE: Please excuse my poor attempt at a tag pun*

The [router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/router) tag is a tag specifying the level three networking device as mentioned form the tag wiki:

> A router is a device that forwards data packets across multiple networks.

Looking at the first age of question for this tag, it seems mist of the time it is abused. Mostly I see questions about router configuration (port forwarding, etc...). These questions would be better fit Super User, or in some rare cases maybe Server Fault.

Another issue with the tag is that people are using it to tag questions about routing on the web (server-side routing or router for a JavaScript framework). While there are a few questions that use the questions correctly, and within a programming context, it seems that for the most part, the tag attracts poor questions.

What do you think should be done? Burninate?

Comment: Massive misuse for off-topic content isn't a valid reason for burnination, but for a concerted cleanup-effort. Which should *start* with making sure the tag-wiki and excerpt don't invite those bad questions too much.

Comment: I add some info to the tag wiki, but I am not sure how the content is. Could you possibly review the edits I proposed?

Comment: @Deduplicator I object. [Previous](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372576/lets-clean-up-postfix-mta) [attempts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331586/should-we-burninate-the-kali-linux-tag/373930#373930) at this tactic have proven fruitless.