# Should we burninate the [kali-linux] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

*The phase 2 of the burnination process described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) is completed and it has been decided that the tag should NOT be removed from the system. It was decided to clean the tag, and the tag is in the process of being cleaned. Please see the answer below to keep track of progress*

---

For some reason, Stack Overflow seems to get a lot of questions about [Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/), a Debian-based distribution with a focus on penetration testing tools.

With very few exceptions, these questions are *always* off-topic for Stack Overflow, and should be closed. (They may be more appropriate on Super User.) Most of them fall into one of a few categories:

- Questions about how to install the distribution to a computer or virtual machine.
- Basic questions about configuring Kali Linux, or about using non-security-specific software on it, such as text editors, web browsers, or video players.
- Questions about using (or abusing) penetration testing tools which are distributed with Kali. These questions may be appropriate on [Information Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

There are a few Kali-related topics which might be appropriate here, but they are much rarer:

- General questions about Linux programming which incidentally mention that the user is using Kali Linux. These questions may be on-topic, but are *highly* unlikely to be specific to Kali; it's not all that different from Debian Linux, or other distributions. These should not be tagged as [kali-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kali-linux), as the distribution's involvement is only incidental.
- Questions about writing software that is truly specific to Kali Linux. These are unicorns. I've never seen one. I'm not sure they even exist.

At this point, I'm not sure why these questions are all ending up here. My first suspicion was that SO was mentioned on a Kali support site, but I can't seem to find anything pointing here. My best guess at this point is that the volume of Kali questions on SO is attracting more.

To slow that process, please help me vote-to-close all of the questions tagged as [kali-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kali-linux), as well as [most of the other questions that show up in a search for "Kali Linux" that are not closed yet](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22kali%20linux%22%20is%3Aquestion%20closed%3Ano).

Comment: maybe edit the tag so that it mentions (bold, all caps) that most kali-linux are off-topic for SO and will be closed.  please don't suggest U&L, we get more than enough low quality kali questions already.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kali-linux gives a slightly different result, with focus on new questions (but obviously misses the ones without the tag).

Comment: @cas Good idea, I did that (except that it doesn't seem to be possible to use markup in a tag description).  Feel free to tweak wording, everyone.

Comment: @zwol - serverfault will hate having kali questions directed to them....they even dislike legit server questions if there's any hint that its for a home or soho server.

Comment: @cas I've edited the tag description to recommend Security SE instead. It's still a bit of a stretch, but at least there's a chance that a *few* Kali questions may fit in there.

Comment: The tag wiki doesn't *need* to recommend an alternative site. It is not our job to find a home for unwanted orphaned questions. If they can't find an appropriate site on their own with a bit of effort, they probably can't compose a valid question. @fedorqui, I'm not sure why you filtered out closed questions. I have a queue of delete votes that haven't been used for today!

Comment: To be fair, people are currently just flagging everything for close in this thread, even those questions which are about programming (scripting) and are just badly researched and only deserve downvotes. Overdoing it is kind of a backlash and might be seen as bad style. Not every question in this tag deserves to be closed. Apart from this, at least 90% is crap.

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q : +58/-3

Comment: Speaking of unicorns, when I looked at the search [this question was at the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823886/what-is-the-macro-for-kali-linux?s=1|112.6318). I guess they do exist!

Comment: @Draco18s actually, that question could be canonicalized around to ask "What is the macro to test a specific distribution?" since that's what it really ask about.

Comment: **Moderator Note** Please don't start burninating the tag before the community has a chance to agree or disagree.

Comment: @BhargavRao, I see that there are no questions left on this thread. Perhaps time to move on?

Comment: @Luuklag, sigh, I didn't expect that to happen. Anyway, [all tag removals must be discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356963/tag-removals-must-be-discussed-and-documented-on-meta), and the rule clearly says that tags shouldn't be removed while it is featured. I'll try to find out the users involved in this removal and mod message them. (Should ask Shog if there's a script to roll back all the tag edits).

Comment: @BhargavRao *"A1(Saying Yes) : +34/-1"* - wait, what? This seems like a mischaracterisation of Gilles's answer, which doesn't opine either way on whether the tag should be burninated, as far as I can see.

Comment: @BhargavRao Just to play the devil's advocate for a minute, doesn't the Meta post you linked to imply that jumping the gun on the burnination process imply that doing so is potentially grounds for suspension?

Comment: @MarkAmery, Fixed it, sorry. I misread his answer as support for burnination. I apologize for that.

Comment: @EJoshuaS, the users were warned, the last few times this happened to smaller tags, so I sent a warning.

Comment: @MarkAmery I think it's semantics: if all the questions merits closure and deletion, would it be any different from burnination?

Comment: @Braiam No, it wouldn't, but that's not what Gilles answer says; there's a big difference between claiming that "a lot" of Kali questions are "crap" and that "all" of them "merits closure". Gilles claimed the former, and I don't think we can safely infer that he (or his upvoters) believe the latter.

Comment: Maybe SO just needs a shadow-tag mechanism (similar to shadow banning but for individual questions)...where questions with certain problematic tags just get dumped in a black hole where no-one can ever see it.

Comment: *"Questions about writing software that is truly specific to Kali Linux. These are unicorns. I've never seen one. I'm not sure they even exist..."* - I believe I have seen two on-topic Kali questions. Also see [std::cout@@GLIBCXX_3.4 can not be used when making a PIE object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52136839/608639) and [Audio streaming using metasploit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50710374/608639). (I usually comment when I encounter one).

Comment: Also, to state the obvious, deleting the tag will not make the off-topic questions go away, and won't stop future off-topic questions. However, it will forgo the ability of self-classification. The site won't be able to provide additional vetting for high-risk tags before the question is asked. (The site performing additional vetting for high risk tags is another unicorn).

Comment: @jww Those aren't specific to Kali Linux. The authors happened to be using it, but the questions are distro-independent.

Comment: Before we do anything with this: can we settle the [the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308736/are-questions-on-programming-tools-installation-configuration-on-topic) of whether questions about installing programming tools is on-topic? I noticed that a lot of questions in this tag on that subject were closed as "general computing."

Comment: At the end, the tag give a context associated with others tags, for me it's a precious information, the environment is often used associated with the technologie on questions. Here it's more a moderation issue.

Comment: The tag is showing 0 questions, should this be updated to [meta-tag:status-complete]?

Comment: @DanNeely Not necessarily. If the consensus we settle on is that we should keep the tag, we'll have a community *un*-burnination to perform. Which will at least be new and novel.

Comment: @MarkAmery, Why do I now have a picture of Trogdor setting up the countryside and building thatched-roof cottages for the people?

Comment: This reminds me of @Gilles question and answer to address a similar issue: [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399626/302105)

Comment: Looks like the consensus is almost clear, I'll leave this for 5~6 more hours and then proceed with the next step.

Comment: "90% of everything is crap. It's the other 10% that matters."

Comment: @jww The existence of certain tags can be seen as evidence that OT questions are on-topic.

Comment: @BhargavRao The community consensus is actually not all that clear to me here - the question has a score of +124, but answers saying "no" have scores of +109 and +25.

Comment: @EJoshuaS, If there are answers that are saying no, then I guess it's better to consider the answers... I'll leave this for another UTC day, if the need be, but I guess the consensus is to clean it up. (Also, apart from [chemistry], this is the first other burnination where I've seen more than 5 downvotes on the question)

Comment: I'm still genuinely unsure which side you were asserting there was a "clear" consensus in favour of, @BhargavRao, so I've got to agree with EJoshuaS that it's not clear at all.

Comment: @Mark, I was looking at the answers and I felt that the consensus did seem quite clear that the only need is a cleanup. Anyway, I don't want to rush things, so I'll wait till tomorrow before ending this. (Anyway, we've waited 769 days to come to this state, waiting one more won't make a difference).

Comment: @BhargavRao Oh, in that case, I agree - I thought you were saying that the consensus was clearly in favor of burnination (which is *not* clear to me, given that a lot of people voted for answers saying "no"). My answer was arguing for cleanup (rather than burnination) and it seems like that's what the other upvoted answer is saying, too.

Comment: I'm for burnination, but not because of the quality of the questions, only because of the quantity of the on-topic ones. Me personally, I can't remember ever having had a Linux programming related question that was specific to the OS. Specific to the desktop environment, sure: don't burninate [kde], [gnome], [mate-desktop] etc! But as far as I'm concerned, we can get rid of [debian], [ubuntu], [fedora] and all the others.

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q : +141/-16 A1 - +119/-6; A2 -; A3 (asking for cleanup) +44/-9; A4 (saying No) +6/-17; A5 (saying No?) +3/-11; A6 (saying Yes) +6/-6. A7 (asking for cleanup) +8/-5. A8 (saying Yes) +4/-7. The community has voted in for a cleanup of the tag, rather than a burnination.

Comment: @BhargavRao - I have to ask... Why are you manually tallying those like that? Can't the Stack Exchange team provide you with something better, like an Infobox that tallies for you like election results? Just saying, it seems like a lot of work for you. Did you sign on for that?

Comment: @BhargavRao - Oh, and by the way, the [crud is still flowing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52472119/608639). If Stack Overflow keeps the tag, maybe they can label it "high risk" and present extra warnings and instructions to users based on it.

Comment: @jww, It seems a bit of manual work, but given that it takes under 5 minutes to tally them, decide, add the CW answer (if we need to burninate) and move forward. I don't think it is worth spending development effort and time on that. I'd rather see the SE devs work on more pressing issues like the 2nd iteration of the SE Quality project, or giving more power tools to those who burninate. (Also, I kinda did sign up for that. Any of the diamond moderators can do it. I was a bit free over the summer, and I took up the task).

Comment: @jww, and for the overflowing crud, I've been watching the tag continuously and have closed many. One way to _reduce_ the number of bad questions would be to add [tag warnings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354934/4099593), but again, just like [seo], people will certainly continue to ask bad questions. As they say, if there's an empty box somewhere on the internet, users will add in their questions.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

SO gets a lot of crap questions about Kali Linux because Stack Exchange gets a lot of crap questions about Kali Linux, and SO is the most visible Stack Exchange site.

No amount of documentation in tag wikis will help. People who don't pay attention where they ask certainly don't pay attention to tag wikis.

There seems to be a growing number of people whose first contact with Linux is Kali. Since Kali is a distribution designed for professionals with a specific purpose, it is no surprise that newbies trying to use it for a different purpose would have trouble with it.

Please **do not recommend Security.SE**. Most questions about Kali Linux are off-topic there, too. Questions about installing Kali, about setting up the network, about configuring the GUI, about using the command line, etc. have nothing to do with security and are off-topic on Security.SE. Questions specifically about using the penetration tools bundled by Kali are on-topic on Security.SE, but usually people who are capable of using those tools are also capable of finding the right site to ask on.

And... **please do not recommend Super User or Unix & Linux either, unless the question is actually answerable**. Most of the questions about Kali that we get on U&L are, simply put, crap — at best they're asked by people who are in way over their head and should be using Ubuntu instead, and at worst they're using by people who can't use a computer or write a sentence in English to save their life. With those crap questions, just downvote, close and move on. If you're feeling kind, leave a comment telling them that Kali is a distribution meant for experienced users to run in a virtual machine, and if they want a user-friendly distribution or if they want to install it then they should use elementary OS, Linux Mint or Ubuntu instead.

And of course do not recommend other sites where Kali questions would be off-topic either. In particular, Kali is not Ubuntu, so any question about Kali is explicitly off-topic on Ask Ubuntu. Server Fault is only about professional system administration, and a Kali user would definitely not be welcome there.

Note that this doesn't mean that the *tag* should be removed. The tag indicates what the question is about. The fact that most questions in a tag are low quality does not mean that the tag itself is not useful, if only as a signpost. **Given that [kali-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kali-linux) is a relevant classification to some on-topic questions, it should not be removed**. Please consider each question individually and treat tagging and closure as independent matters. If the question is off-topic or unanswerable, vote to close it. If the question is not specific to Kali Linux, remove the tag, typically to replace it by [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) if it isn't present already.

Comment: The Golden Rule of Migration applies to this even if it's not actually a migration - Don't Migrate Crap.

Comment: This being said, don't send Kali folks over to Ask Ubuntu either, same reasons.  But it's actually offtopic on our site so...

Comment: @labilbe Don't blame a show for people unable to think for themselves

Comment: @ThomasWard Nah, sending it to AU is a no-no for more obvious reasons (I can't recall the last time it was called Ask Kali, for example).

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος Indeed, just reinforcing the point ;)

Comment: I've temporarily unaccepted this answer to make it clear this discussion is ongoing.

Comment: "Most of the questions a̶b̶o̶u̶t̶ ̶K̶a̶l̶i̶ that we get on U̶&̶L Stack Exchange sites are, simply put, crap." There, I fixed it for you.

Comment: Maybe we should make a "Hollywood Hacker" Stack Exchange specifically to field these type of questions....Perhaps even get Mr. Robot to mention it. Then we won't have to worry about it anymore. :)

Comment: @DuncanXSimpson That's a terrible "rule". Crap should be *auto* migrated (without anyone noticing) so that each site can clean up its own related crap. SO should haven't to deal with other site's crap just because SO is the most popular site.

Comment: @TylerH …but other sites should have to deal with SO's crap because it sounded vaguely related to them? I don't think so.

Comment: I agree with the part where `kali-linux` shouldn't be removed, but the rest seemed wrong and/or overly negative

Comment: @Hack-R I assure you that a vast majority of [tag:kali-linux] questions are not welcome on [security.se], [unix.se] or [su]. It's negative, yes, because there's hardly anything positive to say about those questions. That doesn't make it wrong.

Comment: @duskwuff no, because it *is* related to them. You're also basing that argument on the faulty premise that such questions are "SO's crap" to begin with. Implicit in my suggestion (without anyone noticing) is a not insubstantial amount of work on the system running the network to assist or force users and their questions to end up on a more appropriate site. At any rate, a question about Kali Linux, for example, is more on-topic by default on U&L than SO. Only when it is a programming question is it more on-topic at SO (and not always then, either). *Ad infinitum*.

Comment: @TylerH If I followed your advice and migrated all the crap programming questions from [cs.se], the SO mods would not be happy with me. “Don't migrate crap” is there to stay.

Comment: @Gilles I agree users should not migrate crap and have not suggested that.

Comment: @Gilles Well, you've probably spent well more time on the topic that I. I just think it should be approached more as a salvage/improvement opportunity.

Comment: Possibly mention [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399626/91565) (which you wrote!) as an example of how strongly the non-SO sites hate Kali.

Comment: @TylerH, A good read on the topic [Respect the community – your own, and others’](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/22/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/)

Comment: @BhargavRao I have read that and it's not really relevant here. I think you had the same problem as Gilles in (mis)reading my comments above.

Answer (score 49):

I actually do *not* agree with this burninate request. We have OS-specific tags for other specific versions of operating systems as well, such as [windows-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-8) and [windows-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-10). If we're going to burninate this tag, are we going to burninate them, too?

The mere fact that we're not convinced that there are enough programming questions that are specific to Kali Linux is not, in and of itself, a reason to burninate the tag.

The fact that the tag tends to draw a lot of low-quality questions also isn't necessarily a valid reason to burninate it. There are plenty of tags here, such as [openvpn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openvpn), [licensing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/licensing), and [seo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seo), where the *majority* of new questions are off-topic, so again, if we burninate this tag for that reason, we'd have to burninate all of them too.

With that said, this tag doesn't meet *any* of the burnination criteria:

- This tag is decidedly *not* a Meta tag - it's describing a real topic.
- This tag means the same thing in all common contexts.
- This topic isn't intrinsically off-topic. If it *is* intrinsically off-topic, we should get rid of all other OS-specific tags too.
- The tag *does* add meaningful information to the post. You can argue about whether it adds *more* information than the Linux or Debian tags, but it's still more information than no OS-related tag at all.

That being said, I don't think that this tag meets the burnination criteria, and the arguments in favor of burninating it prove too much and would lead to us needing to burninate a large number of tags if applied consistently.

This should be a cleanup effort, *not* a full burnination.

One more point: the issue of installing programming tools. It's not clear to me that these questions should be closed for being about general computing; at a minimum, since many of these questions pertain to tools used primarily for programming, it's worth discussing whether these questions should be closed. There's a separate question about that [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308736/are-questions-on-programming-tools-installation-configuration-on-topic).

Comment: I do agree with this answer, but wonder if kali-linux is distinct enough from general linux to warrant a separate tag. The main real difference is the tools it comes with, but that's not relevant for programming questions. If we're not going to burninate, I feel very much for making it a synonym with Linux. In contrast to the Windows tags you've provided, I think there are very few kali-linux specific programming considerations.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth You bring up a good point. In my opinion, that's (possibly) a valid reason to make it a synonym, but it's really not a reason for burnination (given that the tag doesn't really meet the published criteria).

Comment: If any OS-specific tag is suddenly proving to be a cesspool of support requests as opposed to questions in regards to development, then absolutely they should be burninated.   Of course, I see the points you're making more as straw men; it would make sense to go back and do any kind of burnination/cleanup effort on any of those other tags if it's warranted.  It just so happens that Kali Linux is fairly infamous for it.

Comment: @Makoto A lot of tags attract plenty of garbage, but that doesn't mean that they all deserve to be burninated.

Comment: Let's try it like this then.  From the Windows 10 tag, [this post seems *reasonable*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52006621/1079354) and on-topic for the site, since it involves publishing an application to the Windows App Store (which is something I'd expect software developers who work on Windows to know).  [This question from Kali Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43708922/wine32-kali-linux-error) is looking to get Wine to work on their machine, which isn't a programming question.

Comment: I haven't seen a serviceable question which was specifically about Kali Linux in the context of development on the site.  We've been rattling this tag around in meta-discussions for *years*.

Comment: Kali linux uses Debian testing as base OS plus kali specific repositories, from a programmer perspective, there's **no difference** between Kali, Debian, Arch and Fedora. You can install kali, change to debian only repos and get a full debian installation.

Comment: @Makoto I will propose to cleanup debian and friends. I just haven't gotten around to write a complete guidance towards the cleanup, but you can simply filter by debian and you will find several off topic questions on that tag.

Comment: Please, do - I would strongly encourage it. :)

Comment: @Makoto I think that we have to make a distinction between "draws a lot of garbage questions" and "meets the criteria for burnination." Strictly speaking, "draws garbage questions" is *not* a criteria for burnination - being vague, ambiguous, inherently off-topic, a Meta tag, etc. *is*.

Comment: if "draws a lot of garbage questions" was a criteria, then we should start with [php]

Comment: @BhargavRao If "draws a lot of garbage questions" was a criteria, then _the entire site_ would be a burnination target. But I digress. :)

Comment: @BhargavRao Yep - not to mention [c], [c++], and any [java] question posted on Sunday night.

Comment: @BhargavRao I think it's semantics: if all the questions merits closure and deletion, would it be any different from burnination?

Comment: @Braiam I'm not convinced that all of them do merit closure and deletion

Comment: @EJoshuaS you need to hang out in [unix.se]

Comment: @EJoshuaS - I added the Kali tag after I noticed a trend of off-topic questions. My hopes was we could classify the off-topic question and treat the tag as high risk. Then, when a new user posed a Kali question, they would get more thorough vetting and blinking neon lights. Unfortunately nothing gets done, like vetting higher risk tags. We just can't seem to get Stack Overflow to do anything about the increasing flow of off-topic junk.

Comment: @EJoshuaS maybe you can provide some links to questions that ARE valid under the tag. I get where you are coming from, but your argument reads like a slippery slope fallacy.

Answer (score 22):

Questions under this tag unfortunately have been retagged before walking through the proper burninate process.

I've created [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/896622/tagged-kali-linux-before-9-9), which lists all questions tagged kali-linux before 9-9-2018, which is before this question got featured and users started to retag.

In my opinion, we don't need to involve Shog9 for this request, but we can discuss the burninate, and if it's approved, we can review questions from this list for closure. If it hasn't, we can rollback the edits on these questions.

Comment: Luckily there are only 82 questions.

Answer (score 16):

Time to un-burninate the tag (Thanks to Mark for coming up with that term):

[image]

## Progress:

The [kali-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kali-linux) tag is in the process of being un-burninated and cleaned. You can help out by reviewing the questions in the following list, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question **and** if the post is about Kali Linux, add the [kali-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kali-linux) tag back,
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the clean up process all closed questions in the following list will be deleted. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

```
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
┃No┃       Status        ┃ Link to the post                                                                                        ┃
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
┃ 0┃       deleted       ┃Gns3-gui won't install because of python3.4 or .5 "is not instalable"                                    ┃
┃ 1┃       deleted       ┃Unable to install gcc 4.9.4 in Kali 2018.2                                                               ┃
┃ 2┃       deleted       ┃Android Studio can't create a new virtual device on Kali and says check idea.log                         ┃
┃ 3┃       deleted       ┃send raw packets in promisc mode pcap                                                                    ┃
┃ 4┃       deleted       ┃Error installing Mobile Security framework on Kali - Oracle java not avialble                            ┃
┃ 5┃       deleted       ┃QRLJacking Error to open browser                                                                         ┃
┃ 6┃       deleted       ┃Pdftk Installation in Kali Linux                                                                         ┃
┃ 7┃       deleted       ┃docker pull stuck pulling fs layer                                                                       ┃
┃ 8┃       deleted       ┃kali linux docker image build script failed - syntax error near unexpected token `;&'                    ┃
┃ 9┃       deleted       ┃How to install python requests in Kali Linux?                                                            ┃
┃10┃     tag removed     ┃Executing metasploit commands using Java                                                                 ┃
┃11┃       deleted       ┃Cannot Install pygtk on Kali Linux                                                                       ┃
┃12┃in CVQ*; tag removed ┃Audio streaming using metasploit                                                                         ┃
┃13┃       deleted       ┃Linux based operating system projects                                                                    ┃
┃14┃     tag removed     ┃PyInstaller outputting .ELF insted of .EXE on kali                                                       ┃
┃15┃       deleted       ┃Error "Failed initializing wireless card(s)" when using Airodump-ng                                      ┃
┃16┃       deleted       ┃airodump-ng wlan0mon not capturing any data                                                              ┃
┃17┃     tag removed     ┃Perl hex replacement in iso                                                                              ┃
┃18┃       deleted       ┃how to fix IP address when using kali linux in virtual box with modem                                    ┃
┃19┃       deleted       ┃How to search for both upper and lower case letter in text file in kali linux                            ┃
┃20┃       deleted       ┃Running python with kali linux gnome-terminal in sublime3                                                ┃
┃21┃       deleted       ┃Bash: Can't sudo -S (snippet of code)                                                                    ┃
┃22┃     tag removed     ┃sed Unknown command `/' in Kali                                                                          ┃
┃23┃       deleted       ┃Makefile Default Error 2                                                                                 ┃
┃24┃       deleted       ┃Error when installing checkinstall and installwatch                                                      ┃
┃25┃       deleted       ┃how to setup a docker image on Arukas.io?                                                                ┃
┃26┃     tag removed     ┃'module' object has no attribute 'STARTUPINFO'                                                           ┃
┃27┃     tag removed     ┃Android Studio 2.3 Gradle sync failed                                                                    ┃
┃28┃       deleted       ┃Pip installation error in kali linux                                                                     ┃
┃29┃       deleted       ┃How do I run a docker image from a Dockerfile?                                                           ┃
┃30┃       deleted       ┃Metasploit-Framework Cannot Load Such File Payload Modules Raspberry Pi 2 ARM                            ┃
┃31┃     tag removed     ┃Use python subprocess module on kali and want to hide the console window                                 ┃
┃32┃     tag removed     ┃Python script for Sambacry exploit encountered bug                                                       ┃
┃33┃     tag removed     ┃What is the macro for Kali Linux?                                                                        ┃
┃34┃     tag removed     ┃Android Virtual Device not installing                                                                    ┃
┃35┃     tag removed     ┃GCC 6.4.0 Error with VMWare player and Kali linux                                                        ┃
┃36┃       deleted       ┃Kali postgres password                                                                                   ┃
┃37┃       deleted       ┃Error in Compiling due to Missing XCursor.h                                                              ┃
┃38┃       deleted       ┃Whats the difference between putting a space after find expression vs not                                ┃
┃39┃       deleted       ┃Why def run() method not executes?                                                                       ┃
┃40┃       deleted       ┃Android studio is not working correctly                                                                  ┃
┃41┃       deleted       ┃How do I download and install libcurl3 Kali?                                                             ┃
┃42┃       deleted       ┃dlib installation on kali gives the runtime error                                                        ┃
┃43┃in CVQ;   tag added  ┃Cannot install pyV8 and pylibemu in kali                                                                 ┃
┃44┃       deleted       ┃Why can't I start the apache2 on kali linux?                                                             ┃
┃45┃     tag added       ┃Fixing error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0 when Installing Teensyduino in Kali           ┃
┃46┃       deleted       ┃Installing php5.6 on Kali Linux                                                                          ┃
┃47┃     tag removed     ┃How to create "native 32 bit" application?                                                               ┃
┃48┃in CVQ;* tag removed ┃SQLmap: usage of -u and -r commands                                                                      ┃
┃49┃       deleted       ┃Python setup.py egg_info Error                                                                           ┃
┃50┃       deleted       ┃python issue with scapy-http httprequest                                                                 ┃
┃51┃       deleted       ┃Unable to connect to inet address in firefox from metasploit                                             ┃
┃52┃       deleted       ┃Why does the ssh service name show up when using nmap commands on Kali Linux vs not showing up on CentOS ┃
┃53┃       deleted       ┃Cant acess the website hosted by virual box                                                              ┃
┃54┃       deleted       ┃Raspi wlan0 mac adress change with hostapd                                                               ┃
┃55┃       deleted       ┃airodump-ng | Save formatted output in RAM                                                               ┃
┃56┃     tag removed     ┃vimrc not accepting mouse-=a command                                                                     ┃
┃57┃       deleted       ┃How do i set the jvm in Java_home                                                                        ┃
┃58┃       closed        ┃error when install python-mysql (kali linux)                                                             ┃
┃59┃     tag removed     ┃gcc on Kali Linux                                                                                        ┃
┃60┃       deleted       ┃import threading is inactive in python 2.7                                                               ┃
┃61┃       deleted       ┃ARP Cache Poisoning py2                                                                                  ┃
┃62┃in CVQ;*  tag added  ┃QSslSocket :cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_server_method in Qt 5.11                              ┃
┃63┃     tag removed     ┃Change images in HTTPResponse with mitmproxy                                                             ┃
┃64┃       deleted       ┃TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable Kail Linux                                                  ┃
┃65┃       deleted       ┃Install linux-headers unable to locate package                                                           ┃
┃66┃       deleted       ┃KALI WSL install Kali-linux-all                                                                          ┃
┃67┃in CVQ;*  tag removed┃Android Studio in Kali Linux : Run button does not do anything at all                                    ┃
┃68┃       deleted       ┃I am trying to install php 7 on my kali linux                                                            ┃
┃69┃       deleted       ┃Unable to create SCAP database in Openvas 9                                                              ┃
┃70┃       deleted       ┃Problems compiling programs as 32-bit in 64 bit Kali linux                                               ┃
┃71┃     tag removed     ┃x11 - ImportError: No module named 'kivy.core.window.window_x11'                                         ┃
┃72┃in CVQ;*  tag removed┃Error while using libplatform/libplatform.h on kali linux                                                ┃
┃73┃     tag removed     ┃Run Python 3.6 script in terminal                                                                        ┃
┃74┃     tag removed     ┃How do I open multiple separate terminal windows in C++?                                                 ┃
┃75┃in CVQ;*             ┃(Kali & Ettercap) Plugin compilation error                                                               ┃
┃76┃       deleted       ┃kali cant mount cdrom?                                                                                   ┃
┃77┃       deleted       ┃'java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError' When Trying to Install Android Studio on Kali Linux             ┃
┃78┃       deleted       ┃scapy http import throwing error                                                                         ┃
┃79┃       deleted       ┃Kali Linux: Run penetration test and generate report for particular site?                                ┃
┃80┃       deleted       ┃Failing to create a rat while using kali linux Ahmyth                                                    ┃
┃81┃       deleted       ┃Metasloit python script stuck on PAYLOAD                                                                 ┃
┃82┃       deleted       ┃(Ettercap) How to correctly compile plugins?                                                             ┃
┃83┃       deleted       ┃Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code in Kali linux 2017.1     ┃
┃84┃       deleted       ┃Kali Linux Rolling: Trying to install Ruby 2.2.2 but getting "__rvm_make -j4" error                      ┃
┃85┃in CVQ;*             ┃“make all” error while compiling TPlink wm722n driver                                                    ┃
┃86┃       deleted       ┃Bash read status information from airbase-ng                                                             ┃
┃87┃       deleted       ┃After use glibc 2.27 many UAF bug can‘t to use                                                           ┃
┃88┃       deleted       ┃How to remote-control veil-evasion with terminal                                                         ┃
┃89┃in CVQ;* tag removed ┃Can't locate isrcore/shellz.pm in @INC (evilgrade download)                                              ┃
┃90┃       deleted       ┃kali linux seacrching for linux headers                                                                  ┃
┃91┃ closed; tag removed ┃Having trouble running cupp.py on windows                                                                ┃
┃92┃       deleted       ┃Request ImportError: No module named "requests" on Kali                                                  ┃
┃93┃       deleted       ┃environment variable not found in gdb                                                                    ┃
┃94┃       deleted       ┃Zip Password cracker not working in Python3.x                                                            ┃
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
* This question is currently in the close-vote-queue and won't Roomba unless closed.
    Just the fact that it's in the CV-queue doesn't mean you should close-vote.  Use
    your own judgement. 

    The question may, or may not, qualify for the Roomba if it's closed.  If it won't
    qualify for the Roomba when closed, then someone should make a choice as to
    re-adding the kali-linix tag back into the question, or not.  If the tag is
    re-added and the question is closed, then the question will be deleted at the end
    of this process, regardless of it qualifies for the Roomba.  If the tag is not
    added, then the question will not be deleted through this un-burnination process.

    If you make a choice to add the tag, please indicate that fact in the status with
    "tag added".  If you make a choice that the tag should not be added, then please
    indicate that with "tag not added", or something similar.
```

(Thanks to Eric, for the list of questions which need to be re-checked for the clean-up)

## Remember that we're doing a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* add the [kali-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kali-linux) tag, if the post is about Kali Linux.

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/closed.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, just flag/close the question it is attached to.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: Another example that SE needs Markdown tables :)

Comment: We are closing and deleting all these questions... the tag would end removed anyways.

Comment: FYI 4 more [kali-linux] questions were asked since this was written (5 days ago), all off-topic.

Answer (score 6):

IMO, there's a principal error here: **tagged by a lot of crap questions `!=` the tag itself is valueless**.

[kali-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kali-linux) itself is **a classification of a specific platform/environment**, and by that it has its value, by having the potential of being applied to the right questions.

The appropriate action we take on this tag, IMO, would be closing the bad questions and removing/replacing the tag if it's irrelevent to the question. Concerns on migration is very well covered in other answers here so I'm not repeating them.

Comment: +1 I agree - "has lots of off-topic questions" is specifically **not** a burnination criteria. The *actual* burnination criteria is "describes something that's *inherently* off-topic" (or is so ambiguous/vague that we we can't tell). Besides, if we accept that as a burnination criteria, a lot more tags than just this one are going to have to go, too.

Comment: @EJoshuaS For SO purposes, there's no need for causation, a correlation is enough. If a tag is a bad question magnet, it's problematic for the site and should be redesigned [to deny support to bad behavior](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373158/what-does-our-long-term-community-need-what-does-our-long-term-community-need-t/373501#373501).

Answer (score -1):

- Since tags at SO indicate the specific technologies directly involved, OS tags aren't even valid tags *on their own* -- they are only valid in conjunction with API/product tags *as clarification for them* if there are differences in those APIs/products between OS releases.

  - So **in principle, OS tags could instead be version-specific tags for products/APIs. They only aren't as a shortcut:** because it's less work this way.
- As such, **if such a tag proves problematic, we can get rid of this shortcut** and make an OS tag into clarification tags...

  - **...if such a clarification is even needed:**

    - In Linux, distinct components/technologies and their versions are well-defined and independent from specific releases. As such, **in *programming* rather than usage questions, knowing just versions of the products and components involved is typically enough to get the picture; an OS tag would only be a clear win for further clarification like paths and configuration options for stock installed software** and such.

Concluding, **due to the rampant abuse, the OS-tag-as-shortcut is more trouble that it's worth is this case** and can thus **be replaced in questions with details that are a part of an MCVE**: versions, environment variables, compilation flags, configuration options etc.

Answer (score -4):

Kali is not a "version of an operating system". It is a brand. You can't use it like [windows-10] or [macos-high-sierra] to indicate that a question applies to a particular API level or set of tools that are only available in a particular version. The use of Kali isn't relevant to a legitimate programming question.
 Destroy the tag with all speed and display a large red banner explaining the purpose of SO if a user tries to enter it. Don't send them somewhere else; simply provide guidance for tagging the question appropriately if they have a question that is on-topic for SO, and tell them to find another resource otherwise.

Comment: We already have tags for Windows, QNX, Ubuntu, Debian, Android, and a wide variety of other operating system brands, versions, and "flavors." By that logic, shouldn't we burninate all of them for being irrelevant to programming questions?

Comment: @EJoshuaS I don't think that Debian is a very good tag either, but the others are distinct target platforms.

Comment: -1, perhaps unfairly, because I don't get what this answer is trying to say. I haven't used Kali, but as I understand it it's a Linux distro. In what sense is it any less a "version of an operating system" than, say, Ubuntu is?

Comment: @MarkAmery it's not. They're both bad. The vast majority of stuff in [ubuntu] is either not programming related, or has something to do with programming but isn't specific to Ubuntu in any way.

Answer (score -12):

If it's a good hint that the question is crap, and that the question would likely be asked whether there is a tag for it or now, i'd say keeping it seems potentially useful. People wanting to quickly cleanup a lot of crap can use the tag to get high-quality crap and easily move it to the trash, with very few false-positives to look for. It could even be the work of a bot. Of course, you could imagine that users would catch on and stop using it, but either they would, and that would at least make them think a bit more about what they are doing, or they wouldn't, and it's a good reason to keep filtering them.

(see related question [Is it dangerous to patrol a tag with issues?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332564/is-it-dangerous-to-patrol-a-tag-with-issues?noredirect=1&lq=1) that users are already doing that.)

Comment: *the question would likely be asked whether there is a tag for it or not* I don't agree. In reality, users - especially new users - almost certainly routinely use the existence of tags as evidence that their question is on-topic (regardless of what the help center says). I recently even saw a question on home improvement that was dutifully tagged [cement] (which is apparently the name of an actual Python framework by the way) - while most cases aren't that blatant, a lot of tags that don't meet the burnination criteria routinely draw off-topic questions for that exact reason.

Answer (score -13):

No.

I don't see bad/-not suitable for SO- questions a reason to remove a tag. I expect them to come whether the tag is there or not. It will just be more problematic to categorise questions that should stay on SO.

Comment: Wait.  You're saying in *spite* of the question being off-topic and unsuitable for the site, we should still keep a tag around for it?

Comment: @Makoto Instead act on removing those questions. If you remove tag, will the question be removed? I want to point out that act on what exactly is bad, not things related to it.

Comment: If we remove (and hopefully blacklist this time) this tag, then there will be no indication that those kinds of questions are permissible on the site.

Comment: This assumes that the existence of bad tags doesn't make people more likely to ask off-topic questions. If anything, most people (especially new users) will take the existence of the tag as evidence that they can ask that particular kind of question here.

Comment: @EJoshuaS That's a fact I don't deny. But the actual fix for that isn't to remove the tag, as a bigger problem lies with the assumption (you mentioned above) made based on tags existence. It can be thought as a practical workaround, but when asked as a question, here on Meta, about its correctness, I am confident that it's incorrect (but practical ATM perhaps?).

Comment: One quick note: according to the burnination criteria, "describes something that is off-topic here" *is* a legitimate reason to burninate the tag. I don't agree with this burnination request, but that's because I think that it's possible to write on-topic questions about this particular subject - if I didn't, I'd advocate for burnination too.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I follow your last point. I think that it's perfectly logical to assume that the existence of a tag is evidence that the question is on-topic. If you don't want people to go into a particular room, close and lock the door - don't leave it open and be surprised when people go in it.

Comment: @EJoshuaS But removing tag is like removing room number (from the entire hotel) as I see it, not locking the room. Why not try restricting unwanted entries instead? What about some actually interested folks who you don't classify as unwanted? Why should they be judged based on others' behaviour? BTW I am not advocating to keep the tag, I see it wrong to remove tag for this reason. A better reason could be 'not enough good questions with this tag'. NOTE: I haven't read your answer yet.

Comment: @Makoto, the last sentence of 0xc0de's answer implies that *some* `kali-linux`-tagged questions are on-topic here and correctly tagged. His argument is not that we should keep around a fundamentally off-topic tag; it's that this *isn't* such a tag, and a large fraction (or even a majority) of questions in a tag being close-worthily bad is not a sufficient reason to justify burnination. FWIW, I think he's probably right on all counts.

Comment: @MarkAmery I think you meant wrong on all counts. Read [2nd question on when to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/213575), [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331586/should-we-burninate-the-kali-linux-tag?cb=1#comment629329_373908) and [this query](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373892/792066).