# Are blender questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope, migration

First off a bit of background.
[Blender](https://www.blender.org/) is a open source program for entirety of the 3D pipeline. <sub>*(If all that means nothing to you then you will understand why I'm asking this.)*</sub>
In May of 2013 blender got its own dedicated SE site:https://blender.stackexchange.com/!

After reading the [what is on topic page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)for SO I quickly see that basic questions about blender (not some of the scripting or three.js questions) do not fit in any of the categories for on topicness.

While blender can use python, the majority of blender questions on SO have nothing to do with scripting at all. (I'm going just from the [blender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blender) tag and not all the extra version tags.)

1,397 blender questions
981 without the python tag
723 without python or three.js tags

Going from these real rough numbers I would say easily half of the blender questions are off topic.

Are these blender questions on topic now?

Why are these blender questions still being asked on SO? Why not just close any new ones as off topic, and direct/migrate to BSE?

---

I'm not asking about the coding questions that happen to have blender involved, but rather the question that have no coding at all. like these examples:

- [Multiple materials or texture on low poly meshes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38703078/3220986)
- [Blender sort elements not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38680133/3220986)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/36746314/3220986
- [How to apply all transformations including scale, rotation etc and make a 3d model defined from world co-ordinates in blender](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36408240/3220986)
  and many many more.

---

What should be done with these questions?

Comment: *"Why are these blender questions still being asked on SO? Why not just close any new ones as off topic, and direct/migrate to BSE?"* Because people see a Blender tag and don't care beyond that. And there is no migration path to BSE, more than likely because it does not fit the requirements to set one up. Just close when appropriate and only point people to BSE if you know for sure it's on-topic there. Don't migrate crap, as the saying goes. P.s. anything older than 60 days can't be migrated.

Comment: You think that's bad, at least there are conceivably programming-related questions that could be asked about Blender. One cannot say the same thing about [Kali Linux](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331586/free-us-from-the-cycle-of-kali-linux), yet those still get asked. It's the curse of a large, popular Q&A site. Everyone comes here with their questions and doesn't bother to reflect first on whether they would be on topic. The only way to solve this is to give more people close-vote powers. Gold tag badge holders are the obvious candidates. They know what is on-topic.

Comment: Note that questions regarding tools primarily used by programmers *are* on topic. The question here is whether Blender should be included in the set of tools that are ontopic together with IDEs, VCSs, Terminals Emulators etc. or not.

Comment: Blender is primarily used by 3D artists, presumably.

Comment: People see Stackoverflow as a place to ask questions to all-knowing computery-people. I wonder if Programming.se makes people more inclined to believe things belong here.

Comment: Wait, so if all the programmers in the world use tool X but all the 3D artists in the world also use tool X, and there are more 3D artists in the world than programmers, does this make tool X off-topic? In other words, Is a primary tool used by programmers off topic if it is not a tool primarily used by programmers!?

Comment: As an aside Blender is used in many tutorials for Unity, a C# based gaming engine / IDE, so could be a contributing factor to why so many Blender questions end up on a programming site.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland going by that example, I should be able to ask about Photoshop, or MS word because programmers use them. Further nobody will say that blender is "primarily used by programmers." To tie in my example, just because I can write macros in MS word, or scripts for photoshop, does not mean I should be asking "How to change the font size in MS Word?" or "Where can I find the magic select tool?"

Comment: @Bakuriu I read that, and contemplated its meaning. As far as I can tell blender can not be considered a scripting tool for that type of category. However I understand and realize that there are and will be scripting question about blender. I'm not questioning those, but rather the questions that have nothing to do with scripting.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I'm not advocating they should be here, just commenting why they may be appearing here (and having a little nit pick at the apparent silliness of the "primarily used by" condition).

Comment: @David Note that the help center states that are on topic question about tools primarily **used by programmers**, not primarily *used to program*. There is a difference. So it doesn't matter whether Blender can be used for scripting but whether it can be used to build applications. In the same way `git` and `mercurial` aren't used to *program*, but are used *by programmers* to organize their code. There's plenty of tools that can be very helpful yet not be strictly related to writing code.