# SE/SO crossover question with different answers?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

This is kind of a weird question, but hear me out.
What do you do if you have a question where you don't know were it best belongs because you don't have the answer to the question yet?

This is kind of confusing, so I'll describe the case I'm struggling with now. I wrote a neural net, and it doesn't work as well as you would predict, and I'm wondering why. It is possible that I screwed up the implementation, in which case the important code and information should be asked to stack overflow. It's also possible that there is a flaw in the architecture of my Neural net, in which case the Artificial intelligence Stack exchange might be more suited. Finally, it might even be possible that my training algorithm is botched, in which case some might argue that mathematics stack exchange would yield the best answers.

So in this case, and in similar cases, where should the question be posted? Is it OK to put it on all 3? How about if I pick one, and I get no answers, is it OK to try another site?

Let me know what you think!

Comment: It's true that some questions, especially related to deep learning, may be hard to position in the Stack. I've been voting to close questions that definitely do not belong here, but sometimes there is no clear decision (more about this [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/352404/1233251)). Would you like an answer that is specific to your example of debugging neural networks, or something more general?

Comment: If you include your actual question and the research you did on each site **and** your reasoning why it doesn't fit (or why it would fit) on any of the sites you selected, you could post a [tag:site-recommendation]. Don't forget to check its [tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/site-recommendation/info).

Answer (score 8):

[No, it's not okay to put the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

For your specific example, here are some ideas to try to narrow down the problem:

- try to solve an easier problem with your Neural Network (NN)
- simplify your NN for the simpler problem - less layers, less nodes
- try your training data on a library NN implementation
- try someone else's training on your NN
- construct [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which you narrowed down using the above steps (among others)

The AI SE is [not about implementations](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) so I wouldn't opt for that site, some AI questions might be on topic on Mathematics, but they are fairly uncommon, every aspect of this is likely on topic on either [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (disclaimer: I don't have much experience with it) or Stack Overflow.

Comment: I would argue that simplifying the NN or the problem is not always appropriate: if the question asks why the model is not performing as expected by the state of the art, using a less complex model can lead to underfitting, making it worse. I can imagine answers then advising the OP to use a more complex network. Let's not forget that not all deep learning issues are bugs in the code. Can you also clarify on this: if we have a clear, specific question "I am solving problem X with this model Y, but I'm not getting good performance, what can I do here?", would you keep it in Stack Overflow?

Comment: Yea, that is kind of the issue I'm having, it isn't failing or anything, and it solves simple problems just fine, but it doesn't do as well as other people have reported when I apply it to a more complicated problem. Since it is a fairly simple implementation, and because I think that it is possible that the issue IS programmatic rather then conceptual, I decided to put it on stack overflow.

Comment: @JustinSanders For such cases I would recommend Data Science SE, as it considers a more "applied" perspective to machine learning. Cross Validated might also be accepted, according to this [meta question](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4510/67965), but I can't speak from experience.