# URL redirect rules for questions identified as duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Are there a list of hard-coded rules for the community to review on URL redirects for questions marked as dupes? I noticed that if one is not logged on MSO (some questions redirect, while others do not...). Though on SO, at random, I checked a few duplicate questions (that have a 1:1 'answered already' by clicking on the link because some questions can be answered already by more than one...) that were `closed:yes` and they show the original question.

---

Example, here on MSO, recent questions of mine closed due to duplicates and these specific ones redirect when **not logged on**:

[Did the Amazon related tags have the brand/picture removed? Or is it a bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415078/did-the-amazon-related-tags-have-the-brand-picture-removed-or-is-it-a-bug?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C4.1078)
redirects to [Is there a list of sponsored tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328236/is-there-a-list-of-sponsored-tags)

[Review queue @username does not prompt auto-complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415240/review-queue-username-does-not-prompt-auto-complete?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C4.1078) redirects to [Full name of user does not always show up when using @-mention in comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260759/full-name-of-user-does-not-always-show-up-when-using-mention-in-comment)

When **logged on** I am able to see the original question and the section above in a light blue box saying ***this question already has an answer here ...***

---

Additionally, I did a search on closed questions here on MSO and clicking the first 2 or 3 questions took me to the question itself, seeing the original question (marked as duplicate) with reference to the question that answers the question. This is the behavior I observed for my duplicate questions only when logged in.

Why would it differ any?

Examples:
[flagging comments that invite to accept the answer, am I doing right?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405759/flagging-comments-that-invite-to-accept-the-answer-am-i-doing-right?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C3.1339)
[SE/SO crossover question with different answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354028/se-so-crossover-question-with-different-answers?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C3.1339)