# Tag suggestion: Wiremod and/or E2 (revised)

Tags: feature-request, tags

This was inspired by reviewing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65459590/gmod-entity-spawning).

The revised question after [the initial question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404035) was closed for the lack of details and clarity.

## Tag name

- `e2` (with `expression2` and `expression-2` mapping to `e2`), AND/OR
- `wiremod` (the tags above mapping to it)

## Tag reasoning (+ history)

There is an old video-game called *[Garry's Mod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garry%27s_Mod)*,

- *Garry's Mod* runs on the [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_(game_engine)) engine inherited from *[Half-Life 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-Life_2)*, with the custom, added in support of LUA scripts
- Many mods for *Garry's Mod* exist that enhance the gaming experience with their custom scripts. One of the most popular one is **Wiremod** ([GitHub page](https://github.com/wiremod))
- Within Wiremod there are various peculiar items (screens, buttons, radios or what not); but also it has its own advanced scripting language called **Expression2** (or E2). It runs upon what the *Source* engine *and* the base LUA scripts foundation. People may create impressive things with E2 scripts, such as [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OT-F1ISZnBA) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CiC9eOWlIo). The language itself is similar to Lua, but it does not strictly follow Lua style *and* is not compatible with Lua
- There exist unofficial, yet popular, enhancements to the E2 language, such as E2 Extras or Expression Advanced, which are colloquially fall under E2 (and aren't within the scope of suggestion)

## Why the tag and such questions are on-topic for Stack Overflow

Because E2, despite running upon Lua, is a very different language than Lua (see examples below). Wiremod (including E2) itself does not allow for the direct Lua coding.

## How the tag helps in categorizing and finding those questions

The E2 and Wiremod questions become easier to find and categorise.

## Initial tag excerpt and wiki for the new tag

For Wiremod,

> Wiremod is the *Garry's Mod* in-game collection of entities connectable by data wires, which allows for the creation of advanced contraptions.

For E2,

> E2 (also known as Expression2 or Expression 2) is the *Garry's Mod* in-game language bundled with the Wiremod addon, which allows for advanced in-game devices creation and manipulation

## Examples of questions that should have such a tag

- [Issue with the Microsoft Translation API in Expression 2 on GMOD Wire](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19356537)
- [Garry's mod Expression 2 for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34840816)
- [Spatial Rotation in Gmod Expression2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1210007)
- [Garry's Mod expression 2 custom texture](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65513665)
- [How to create an rectangle in a 3d area via vector&angle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30898186) - probably the top-quality question and answer
- [How would I convert a MIDI file into a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16030538)
- [Only check out trunk of a git using SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23173837) - about SVN and Git, but in part about the Wiremod development
- [Gmod Expression 2 Text Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35954655)

## Examples of questions that should **NOT** have such a tag

90% of these [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=garry%27s%20mod%20%5Blua%5D). Most of the questions about *Garry's Mod* LUA are about Lua itself, and not Wiremod / LUA

## Conclusion

I suggest that we create the Wiremod and/or Expression2 tags, so the relevant questions can have the appropriate tags.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvoted with no comments. Even if y'all disagree with this proposal, I'd much rather have people asking whether we should *create* specific tags, as opposed to having to think about re-tagging and burnination after the fact.

Comment: I cannot comment on the technologies, but a tag as nondescript as ``e2`` seems bad to me unless it is very well-known technology/name. At the very least, it looks like an invitation to mistype/mistag ``ec2``. ``WireMod-e2`` or simply no tag in favour of just ``WireMod`` seems more reliable.

Answer (score -4):

I don't believe we need or want these tags, for the simple reason that I don't believe there are many people who would be interested in watching and answering questions around them, for the simple reason that the questions asked in relation to Wiremod are almost universally terrible garbage posted by people who don't understand programming and don't want to, because they're just trying to get random scripts they found on the internet to work.

And that's not what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the technology here so I'm not sure whether the tag is actually necessary, but just having a high proportion of bad questions isn't a valid argument against it any more than it was for [kali-linux](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331586/should-we-burninate-the-kali-linux-tag).

Comment: Just because a tag attracts bad questions doesn't mean it should be removed or something. Lets remove [tag:python] and [tag:regex] while we're at it.