# Let's clean up [postfix-mta]

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

The [requested synonym](/questions/332532/synonym-postfix-postfix-mta-seems-to-have-been-reverted#comment619436_332532) [postfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postfix) -> [postfix-mta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postfix-mta) was recently accepted (thanks Bhargav!) but this still requires a significant cleanup.

By informal off-the-cuff estimate, I would guess

- Around 5% of the remaining questions with [postfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postfix) are on-topic for Stack Overflow, and should be retagged [postfix-mta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postfix-mta);
- Around another 5% should be retagged with [postfix-notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postfix-notation) and reviewed for possible closing as duplicates or etc, but are probably as such not horribly off-topic;
- The remaining approx 90% are general computing and should generally be closed, often with a pointer to [[sf]](//serverfault.com/) but occasionally also [[su]](//superuser.com/) and/or [[ubuntu.se]](//askubuntu.com) and/or [[unix.se]](//unix.stackexchange.com)

How you can help:

- Review the questions, retag and/or close vote

  - I have not retagged the ones I voted to close, on the theory that they will be [roomba](/help/roomba)'d away and bumping them to the home page is not desired or useful. Of course, if something doesn't meet the Roomba criteria, that needs to be taken into consideration.
- Spend a bunch of close votes in the [close review queue with the tag filter set](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=postfix) to [postfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postfix) or perhaps [postfix-mta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postfix-mta)
- Alternatively, approach the bot [Queen](https://github.com/SOBotics/SOCVFinder/blob/master/quickGuide.md) in a chat room near you where she is present; I suppose the [duplicate posts](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117458/duplicate-posts) chat room would be acceptable if you are not currently in a room where Queen is present.

  - `@Queen 5 [postfix]` asks her to retrieve a batch of five close votes from the queue for you to review. It will take a few seconds.
  - You can respond `@Queen done` to the reply you got when you are done reviewing.

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Looks like the close vote link doesn't work -- the filter gets redirected to [tag:postfix-mta] but the ones with pending close votes are still [tag:postfix]

Comment: Posted a separate question about that: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372578/close-vote-tag-filter-should-include-synonym

Comment: Is [tag:postfix-mta] even on topic? I couldn't find where in it you could do any programming. Settings up rules and such is not generally considered programming. If it's off topic, the questions could just be deleted in bulk and the tag burninated after retagging those about the notation.

Comment: Asked https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372581/is-postfix-mta-on-topic-should-it-be-narrowed-down about clarifying the tag's definition.

Answer (score 11):

There are 1,422 questions that are tagged as [postfix-mta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postfix-mta). So this can be handled in a similar way to the large tag burninations, where we cleanup before the tag is removed. (I know that you've provided most of the information, but adding this as answer just in general).

Don't go through the entire list of questions. It would just be additional work and very much draining. Remember that [the movement burnination had 900 questions and took 15 days with all the additional help because of the featured burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371415/4099593).

#### Start from the corners:

These are the ones which are the relatively straight forward.

- Go through the list of [negatively voted, but not closed posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostfix-mta%5D+score%3A..-1+is%3Aq+closed%3A0&mixed=0) (91 as of now). Add in a close vote if needed.
- Go through the list of [unanswered posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostfix-mta%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano&mixed=1) (110 as of now). Add in a close vote or retag if needed.
- Go through the list of [posts with 1 unaccepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostfix-mta%5D+score%3A0+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3A0+answers%3A1..1&mixed=0) (101 as of now). Add in a close vote or retag if needed.

Don't worry about the closed posts, they don't harm us now.

#### Brush the edges:

This is where it gets hard.

- You mention that most of the questions are off-topic as they are about general computing and not about programming. Go through the list [of open posts with no code in them](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostfix-mta%5D+hascode%3A0+is%3Aq+score%3A..10+closed%3A0&mixed=0) (243 as of now). Add in a close vote if needed.
- Search for posts [which do not contain any of the top related tags](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostfix-mta%5D+-%5Bemail%5D+-%5Bsmtp%5D+-%5Blinux%5D+closed%3A0+is%3Aq&mixed=1) (377 as of now). These would again mostly be retags. Tidy them up and retag if needed.
- Search for language tags along with [postfix-mta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postfix-mta). (For example [with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postfix-mta+java)). These would be related to the polish notation rather than the postfix-mta. Retag them if needed.

#### Seek help in chat:

We all are volunteers. It is not just your duty to keep Stack Overflow clean, it is the duty of all of us. Contact others in chat to help your cause. Check out these:

- [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) : they can help you vote to close the questions by filtering in the close vote queue.
- [SOBotics](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics) : they can help you vote to close questions by using [sophisticated tools](https://stackapps.com/questions/6910/socvfinder-providing-enjoyable-reviewing-live-duplicate-notifications-and-cher).
- Language specific chat rooms.

If someone helps, then it's good for us. If no one helps, atleast  you tried your best.

Good Luck!

Comment: "Mail" is not a very distinguishing filter keyword. Many of the 291 without "mail" contain "email" or "SMTP". Other popular email terms are "DKIM" and "Dovecot", though these are almost by definition SeverFault questions.

Comment: @tripleee I used "mail" not to figure out those which are off-topic, but those which need retags. Many of the ones without the word are related to the [postfix-notation], so those can be retagged easily.

Comment: Just a sec, I wonder what I was looking at, but when I use that query today, looks like all of them are related to [postfix-mta]. Removed that query.

Comment: It's not a bad conjecture *per se* but the search needs more email-related exclusion keywords to focus on the non-email questions. Not in a place where I can play around with this right now, but hope to be able to revisit tomorrow.