# Close vote tag filter should include synonym

Tags: bug, review-queues, tag-synonym-process, filtering

Recently [postfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postfix) got redirected to [postfix-mta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postfix-mta) which means that now, if you visit the close vote queue looking for remaining [postfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postfix) questions with pending close votes, you see ... nothing.

I know for a fact that there are dozens of pending [postfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postfix) close votes whereas apparently there are no pending close votes for the proper [postfix-mta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postfix-mta) tag currently.

The tag filter should include synonyms, or perhaps even allow you to search strictly for the posts which have a particular tag synonym.

Comment: Tangentially related: [my recent \[clean-up\] post for \[postfix\]](/questions/372576/lets-clean-up-postfix-mta)

Comment: knowing that tag filtering is already [notoriously heavy on the performance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244335/loading-next-item-from-the-close-vote-queue-ends-in-an-error) I'm afraid adding synonyms to the equation will tumble the review queue building.

Comment: Then as a fallback perhaps expose [postfix] as an option so you can select whether you want [postfix-mta] proper or [postfix] really?

Comment: @rene poor hamsters can barely read the small letters on the tags...